# Output multiple instances of heredoc with for loop

Tags: php

I am trying to get a heredoc to echo multiple times with different id's but it seems to be overwriting the existing one and replacing it with a new instance. Maybe this is not possible to do, I would like to use this method to dynamically generate several different div's with the same class but different id's that are pulled from a MySQL DB my code is below.

```
<?php
$next = 10;
$i=0;
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
$str = <<<EOD
        <div class="brandon" id="$next">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <p>I am a paragraph inside the brandon class div!</p>
        </div>
EOD;
$next++;
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't do anything with `$str` before you reassign it.

Comment: What a squid move thanks for pointing that out I forgot to echo inside the loop haha I just retried it and it worked perfect!

Comment: No problem, in fact you could take Igor's answer and just `echo` after the loop. It would be slightly better, performance wise. (If you're trying to avoid any messages, notice or otherwise, declare `$str = ''` before entering the for loop when using concatenation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `$str .= <<<EOD ....The rest...`